# Default code from Cocos2d-V3 isn't working at all?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I ran the default code provided with the cocos2d template
but doesn't seems to work. 
But a tutorial at Ray Wenderlich says it should be working.

I Couldn't get any far from boilerplate code.
when I ran the initial code provided by default. got crashed
with the following out put :-

```
cocos2d: cocos2d-iphone version 3.0.alpha
cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO
cocos2d: OS version: 6.1 (0x06010000)
cocos2d: GL_VENDOR: Apple Computer, Inc.
cocos2d: GL_RENDERER: Apple Software Renderer
cocos2d: GL_VERSION: OpenGL ES 2.0 APPLE
cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 4096
cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS: 8
cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 4
cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
cocos2d: GL supports shareable VAO: NO
AudioStreamBasicDescription: 2 ch, 44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved
2014-02-10 18:12:19.669 Cocos2DSimpleGame[2532:16103] Error '!obj' trying to fetch default input device's sample rate
2014-02-10 18:12:19.670 Cocos2DSimpleGame[2532:16103] Error getting audio input device sample rate: '!obj'
2014-02-10 18:12:19.671 Cocos2DSimpleGame[2532:16103] AQMEIOManager::FindIOUnit: error 'NoHW'
2014-02-10 18:12:19.672 Cocos2DSimpleGame[2532:12203] AURemoteIO::Initialize failed: -10851 (enable 2, outf< 2 ch, 44100 Hz, Float32, non-inter> inf< 2 ch, 0 Hz, Int16, inter>)
2014-02-10 18:12:19.673 Cocos2DSimpleGame[2532:13e03] <0xb0197000> AQMEIOManager::FindIOUnit: error 'NoHW'
(lldb)
```

What am i missing here ?

PS:- I am using Xcode 4.6.2

Comment: Are you on virtual machine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760399/error-getting-audio-input-device-sample-rate-obj

Comment: Try Xcode 5, it's possible that cocos2d nor tutorial have been tested with Xcode 4.x. There doesn't seem to be an error (crash) though, so perhaps the execution simply stopped at a breakpoint? (blue marker just to the left of the source code editor)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D : what if i turn in-built sound engine off. is there any way to do this in the default code. i am new to cocos2d.

Comment: you could comment out every audio related code in your project.